# Injecting Map with Enum as value in Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, enums

I'm looking on to how I can inject a `Map<Integer, CustomEnumType>` in Spring, not using `app-context.xml` but using `@Bean(name = "customMap")` annotations. When I try to inject it by doing

```
@Inject
Map<Integer, CustomEnumType> customMap;
```

it complains because apparently it cannot find any injectable dependency of type `CustomEnumType`. However `CustomEnumType` is just an enumeration, not something that is supposed to be injected. I just want to use it as the `value` type of my map.

One solution is to create an injectable wrapper object that will contain the `Map` as a field but I'd like to avoid unnecessary clutter. It is also more clean and readable to see the type of `Map` being injected.

Comment: Was the question badly formatted? Did someone not understand what I was asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently `@Inject` and `@Autowired` fail to correctly find the type of `@Bean` method they need to use. However, using `@Resource(name = "customMap")` everything worked perfectly. There was no problem with the map creation even if the values were enumerations. The method used was:

```
@Bean(name = "customMap")
public Map<Integer, CustomEnumType> getCustomMap() {
  Map<Integer, CustomEnumType> map = new HashMap<>();
  map.put(1, CustomEnumType.type1);
  map.put(2, CustomEnumType.type2);
  //...
  return map;
}
```

and injected using

```
@Resource(name = "customMap")
Map<Integer, CustomEnumType> customMap;
```

Note that `CustomEnumType` has no constructors defined and no values are assigned to the enumeration. In my case this was also impossible to do from the beginning since the `CustomEnumType` class is a dependency we cannot edit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to inject Enums, instead, try to inject int values.

Enums are indeed classes, however, you can't create an instance/object of them. their constructor access modifier can be `private` only, that's another proof why you can't have instances of them.

With that being said, you can't have Beans of Enum, because there is no way to construct them.

The solution is to give each member in your enum, an int value, and just inject that int value.

***For example:***

```
public enum Color {
    white(0),
    black(1);

    private int innerValue;

    private Color(int innerValue) {
        this.innerValue = innerValue;
    }

    public int getInnerValue() {
        return innerValue;
    }
}
```

Now, let's say I want to inject the value 1, which is black in my Enum. To another Class ***via its constructor***. Then my constructor will look like this:

```
public Canvas(String id, int color) {
    this.id = id;
    this.color = Color.getColorByInt(color);
}
```

Now, let's say that the xml configuration file containing this:

```
<bean id="myCanvas" class="com.my.package.Canvas">
 <constructor-arg name="id" value="9876543" />
 <constructor-arg name="color" value="1" /> 
 <!-- This is the black value for myCanvas bean -->
</bean>
```